# What ProGuard configuration do I need for Firebase on Android?

Tags: android, firebase, proguard

When using the [Firebase](https://www.firebase.com/) SDK for Android apps, I keep getting warnings and errors like these (in Eclipse):

```
Warning ... can't find referenced class ...
Warning: there were ... unresolved references to classes or interfaces ...
You may need to specify additional library jars (using '-libraryjars') ...
```

Unfortunately, Firebase doesn't have any official documentation about its use with ProGuard.

What directives do I need for my apps to successfully compile releases with Firebase when obfuscated with ProGuard?

Comment: See also [Configure ProGuard](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start/#proguard)

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not resolve the Firebase issue for the Coinverse app. You may see the full code [here](https://github.com/AdamSHurwitz/Coinverse).

Comment: Is there a similar configuration for Firebase Firestore databases using ProGuard as there is when using a Realtime database, outlined in the _[Configure Proguard](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start/#proguard)_ section?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Based on my personal tests, it turned out something along these lines is necessary for Firebase-enhanced Android apps to compile with ProGuard.

In any case, you have to add `-keepnames class com.my.package.beans.** { *; }` if you are using custom objects in your Firebase, i.e. beans or POJOs.

**Firebase SDK 1.0.18:**

```
-keepnames class com.firebase.** { *; }
-keepnames class com.shaded.fasterxml.jackson.** { *; }
-keepnames class org.shaded.apache.** { *; }
-keepnames class javax.servlet.** { *; }
-dontwarn org.w3c.dom.**
-dontwarn org.joda.time.**
-dontwarn org.shaded.apache.commons.logging.impl.**
```

**Firebase SDK 1.1.1:**

```
-keep class com.firebase.** { *; }
-keep class org.shaded.apache.** { *; }
-keepnames class com.shaded.fasterxml.jackson.** { *; }
-keepnames class javax.servlet.** { *; }
-keepnames class org.ietf.jgss.** { *; }
-dontwarn org.w3c.dom.**
-dontwarn org.joda.time.**
-dontwarn org.shaded.apache.**
-dontwarn org.ietf.jgss.**
```

**Firebase SDK 2.0.0:**

```
-keep class com.firebase.** { *; }
-keep class org.apache.** { *; }
-keepnames class com.fasterxml.jackson.** { *; }
-keepnames class javax.servlet.** { *; }
-keepnames class org.ietf.jgss.** { *; }
-dontwarn org.w3c.dom.**
-dontwarn org.joda.time.**
-dontwarn org.shaded.apache.**
-dontwarn org.ietf.jgss.**

# Only necessary if you downloaded the SDK jar directly instead of from maven.
-keep class com.shaded.fasterxml.jackson.** { *; }
```

**Last resort:**

```
-keep class !com.my.package.** { *; }
```

**Notes:**

Any official guideline would be welcome. The `-dontwarn` directives are obviously dangerous, code may break at points that I have not tested. Furthermore, the above rules are quite permissive and other rules may better optimize your APKs.

Comment: @JennyTong: Thanks! Any explanation for the changes? I can't find any `org.apache.**` or `com.fasterxml.jackson.**` classes in the SDK, only the `shaded` versions.

Comment: I had to add `-keepattributes Signature` to let jackson work properly. Ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28433281/how-to-include-typereference-proguard-rule

Comment: @RiccardoCasatta You're right, this is required. I just forgot to mention it because I have this attribute, anyway.

Comment: From our Slack channel: "you will need to add the following line if you're using FirebaseUI: `-dontwarn com.firebase.ui.auth.**`"

Comment: You saved my day with "if you are using custom objects in your Firebase, i.e. beans or POJOs". My app was crashing on production cause not having this rule. Thanks!!

Comment: If you use AdMob add `-keep class com.google.android.gms.internal.** { *; }` this will fix *IllegalArgumentException: Stack size becomes negative after instruction [23] invokestatic #46 in [com/google/android/gms/internal/ads/zzaq.zzf(Ljava/lang/String;)J]*

Comment: i didn't know what BEAN/POJOS mean, lol
googled it, Beans/Pojos are called model classes in java, i.e for encapsulating data. 
thought it might be helpful for others like me :D

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not resolve the Firebase issue for the Coinverse app. You may see the full code [here](https://github.com/AdamSHurwitz/Coinverse).

Comment: `@Keep` annotation can also be used to preserve data classes. Tested and works for Firebase: https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data#use_keep_annotations

Answer (score 17):

I found this in Firebase documentations:

When using Firebase Realtime Database in your app along with ProGuard you need to consider how your model objects will be serialized and deserialized after obfuscation. If you use DataSnapshot.getValue(Class) or DatabaseReference.setValue(Object) to read and write data you will need to add rules to the proguard-rules.pro file:

```
# Add this global rule    
-keepattributes Signature

# This rule will properly ProGuard all the model classes in 
# the package com.yourcompany.models. Modify to fit the structure
# of your app.
-keepclassmembers class com.yourcompany.models.** {
*;
}
```

Comment: Could you provide a link to the documentation?

Comment: @SalicBlu3, here is the documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start#proguard.

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not resolve the Firebase issue for the [Coinverse app](https://github.com/AdamSHurwitz/Coinverse).

Comment: `@Keep` annotation can also be used to preserve data classes. Tested and works for Firebase: https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data#use_keep_annotations

Answer (score 15):

## 2021 answer

Use `@Keep` annotation before your data classes so they're retained by proguard. It's a part of AndroidX for both [Java](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/annotation/Keep) and [Kotlin](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/annotation/Keep). Works for Firebase, Jetpack Navigator and Retrofit.

```kotlin
@Keep
data class Listing(
    val id: String = "",
    val name: String = ""
)
```

[According to documentation:](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/annotation/Keep)

> Denotes that the annotated element should not be removed when the code is minified at build time. This is typically used on methods and classes that are accessed only via reflection so a compiler may think that the code is unused.

Comment: WoW! you are a life saver with a very elegant solution! Thanks man :)

Comment: Google could do better by updating its documentation.

Comment: You still have to add `-keep class com.google.firebase.** { *; }` otherwise your app will not work on Samsung devices, please refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59883426/2430555

Comment: Have tested on Samsung devices, didn't face any issue. We don't have this Proguard rule.

Answer (score 9):

It's not really official documentation, but Firebase did show some basic proguard rules in one of their Github repositories. https://github.com/firebase/AndroidChat/blob/master/app/proguard-rules.pro

```
# Basic ProGuard rules for Firebase Android SDK 2.0.0+
-keep class com.firebase.** { *; }
-keep class org.apache.** { *; }
-keepnames class com.fasterxml.jackson.** { *; }
-keepnames class javax.servlet.** { *; }
-keepnames class org.ietf.jgss.** { *; }
-dontwarn org.apache.**
-dontwarn org.w3c.dom.**
```

Comment: Thanks for this source! The differences to my configuration (see other answer) seems to be that they dropped the `dontwarn` rules for `org.joda.time.**`, `org.shaded.apache.**` and `org.ietf.jgss.**` and instead included one for `org.apache.**`.

Comment: You're welcome. Just wanted to add it since it was from Firebase itself and also since it was slightly different from your personal tests.

Answer (score 3):

Following up on the other answers, using Firebase 2.4.1 I only had to include the following in my proguard config (YMMV):

```
-keep class com.firebase.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.fasterxml.**
```

Answer (score 3):

The configuration for firebase 2.5.2 seems changed. This is what is working for me:

```
-keep class com.firebase.** { *; }
-keep class org.apache.** { *; }
-keepnames class com.shaded.fasterxml.** { *; }
-keepnames class com.fasterxml.jackson.** { *; }
-keepnames class javax.servlet.** { *; }
-keepnames class org.ietf.jgss.** { *; }
-dontwarn org.apache.**
-dontwarn org.w3c.dom.**
```

Answer (score 2):

My working set for **Firebase SDK 2.4.2**:

```
-keep class com.firebase.** { *; }
-keepnames class com.fasterxml.jackson.** { *; }
-keepnames class javax.servlet.** { *; }
-keepnames class org.ietf.jgss.** { *; }
-dontwarn org.w3c.dom.**
-dontwarn org.joda.time.**
-dontwarn org.shaded.apache.**
-dontwarn org.ietf.jgss.**
-dontwarn com.firebase.**
-dontnote com.firebase.client.core.GaePlatform
```

Comment: So it's just the last four entries that are new, right? Maybe a `-dontwarn com.firebase.**` is sufficient here?

Answer (score 1):

I also struggled with this.
Thanks to user4989692 and Ugo for pointing me the right direction.

Here is what worked for me:

build.gradle

```
    buildTypes {
    debug {
        minifyEnabled false
        shrinkResources false
        useProguard false
        debuggable true
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        useProguard true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
}
```

proguard-rules.pro

```
-dontwarn org.w3c.dom.**
-dontwarn org.joda.time.**
-dontwarn org.shaded.apache.**
-dontwarn org.ietf.jgss.**
-dontwarn com.firebase.**
-dontnote com.firebase.client.core.GaePlatform

-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keepattributes InnerClasses,EnclosingMethod

-keep class com.YOUR-APP-DOMAIN.** { *; }

# Basic ProGuard rules for Firebase Android SDK 2.0.0+
-keep class com.firebase.** { *; }

-keepnames class com.fasterxml.jackson.** { *; }
-keepnames class javax.servlet.** { *; }
-keepnames class org.ietf.jgss.** { *; }
```

Comment: won't keep com.YOUR-APP_DOMAIN simply disable all of Proguard? This seems really wrong.

Comment: According to firebase you need instead:                                                      
-keepclassmembers class com.yourcompany.models.** {
  *;
}   just the models you are using together with the real time database!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Firebase Realtime Database, the model objects will be serialized and deserialized after obfuscationstrong text

```
-keep class com.yourdevelopername.urappname.** { *; }
```

Comment: Did the approach in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start#proguard) not work for you @Kaiffi?

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not resolve the Firebase issue for the Coinverse app. You may see the full code [here](https://github.com/AdamSHurwitz/Coinverse).

Answer (score 1):

This is why when you do clean architecture is easy to fix, look at this scenario, if I had multiple firebase requests from multiple files in my app it would be a mess to try to keep single classes for firebase to work, so, if we have a modularized code and we store all our requests and data model inside a data layer it would be so much easy to keep just the classes that uses firebase instead of the whole project, doing this will be better to shrink more the apk size also

[image]

```
-keep class com.mypackage.data.** {*;}
```

Comment: this is what we all looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I have added the same ones that everyone has shown:

```
# Firebase
-keep class com.firebase.** { *; }
-keep class org.apache.** { *; }
-keepnames class com.fasterxml.jackson.** { *; }
-keepnames class javax.servlet.** { *; }
-keepnames class org.ietf.jgss.** { *; }
-dontwarn org.apache.**
-dontwarn org.w3c.dom.**
```

But I also have this one that I discovered by myself, because I couldn't find anyone who added it:

```
-keep class com.google.android.gms.** { *; }
```

And the firebase services work perfectly for me:

Dynamic Link, FireStorage, Auth, Realtime DataBase, Firestore

Answer (score 0):

It solves my problem

Add this to your proguard-rules file

```
-optimizations !class/merging/*
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not resolve the Firebase issue for the Coinverse app. You may see the full code [here](https://github.com/AdamSHurwitz/Coinverse).