# How to include TypeReference ProGuard rule

Tags: jackson, proguard

I have already included following line to keep all files inside the package.

```
        -keep class com.fasterxml.** { *; }
```

I am getting following exception.

```
        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Internal error:             TypeReference constructed without actual type information
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference.<init>(SourceFile:36)
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found the solution. Adding the following into the ProGuard-rules or Config file solved the issue.

```
-keepattributes Signature
```