# Android Firebase app only failing when downloaded from PlayStore

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an app that successfully runs on my device when installed locally via Android Studio. However, after uploading the app to the PlayStore and installing from there, I get a Failed to bounce to type error when querying data from Firebase. Why would the app only fail when downloaded from the PlayStore?

com.firebase.client.FirebaseException: 
Failed to bounce to type at com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source)

Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "time" (class ciceroapps.tether.na.j), not marked as ignorable (0 known properties: ])

Comment: The error occurs when Firebase (specifically: the Jackon library that Firebase uses/embeds) is unable to serialize or deserialize a JSON node to a Java class. Did you specify the necessary proguard settings, to ensure the shaded classes aren't stripped and your model classes remain untouched? See http://stackoverflow.com/a/26274623/209103

Comment: Extremely helpful. Thank you so much Frank!

Comment: If that was the cause, I'll mark your question as a duplicate.

Comment: I believe this was my problem. How would I be able to accurately test if the application is working now without uploading the new version to the PlayStore?

Comment: Typically the Proguard rules are applied to release builds of your apk in the build.gradle file of you app. See http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html for more info.