# Android Studio Proguard troubles

Tags: android, proguard

I am trying to hide the code in my app with the use of proguard.  I can generate a signed APK in debug mode but not in release mode.  I keep on getting errors.  I am trying to search and find answers but I am stumped at the moment.  The error I am getting is

```
Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkReleaseManifest
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2321Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72321Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2321Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72321Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42321Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2321Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareReleaseDependencies
:app:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
:app:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileReleaseSources
:app:lintVitalRelease
:app:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease
:app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease
ProGuard, version 5.2.1
Reading input...
Reading program jar [C:\Users\P\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.firebase\tubesock\0.0.12\6ec0bbd3e161a73ed672284b587fd32309a86d7a\tubesock-0.0.12.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [C:\Users\P\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.core\jackson-core\2.2.2\d20be6a5ddd6f8cfd36ebf6dea329873a1c41f1b\jackson-core-2.2.2.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [C:\Users\P\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.firebase\firebase-client-jvm\2.5.2\91731b8f5868a3e8a8a773f29b8d06b5c358f5bb\firebase-client-jvm-2.5.2.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [C:\Users\P\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.core\jackson-annotations\2.2.2\285cb9c666f0f0f3dd8a1be04e1f457eb7b15113\jackson-annotations-2.2.2.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [C:\Users\P\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.core\jackson-databind\2.2.2\3c8f6018eaa72d43b261181e801e6f8676c16ef6\jackson-databind-2.2.2.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [C:\Users\P\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support\support-annotations\23.2.1\support-annotations-23.2.1.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [C:\Users\P\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.firebase\firebase-client-android\2.5.2\f19f10d6276aa0b380e2d05d2ab3272d693a5433\firebase-client-android-2.5.2.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [C:\Users\P\Desktop\RedHillCarWash2\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\design\23.2.1\jars\classes.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [C:\Users\P\Desktop\RedHillCarWash2\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\23.2.1\jars\classes.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [C:\Users\P\Desktop\RedHillCarWash2\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\animated-vector-drawable\23.2.1\jars\classes.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [C:\Users\P\Desktop\RedHillCarWash2\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\support-vector-drawable\23.2.1\jars\classes.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [C:\Users\P\Desktop\RedHillCarWash2\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\recyclerview-v7\23.2.1\jars\classes.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [C:\Users\P\Desktop\RedHillCarWash2\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\support-v4\23.2.1\jars\classes.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [C:\Users\P\Desktop\RedHillCarWash2\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\support-v4\23.2.1\jars\libs\internal_impl-23.2.1.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [C:\Users\P\Desktop\RedHillCarWash2\app\build\intermediates\transforms\mergeJavaRes\release\jars\2\1f\main.jar] (filtered)
Reading program directory [C:\Users\P\Desktop\RedHillCarWash2\app\build\intermediates\classes\release] (filtered)
Reading library jar [C:\Users\P\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-23\android.jar]
Reading library jar [C:\Users\P\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-23\optional\org.apache.http.legacy.jar]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [android.net.http.SslError]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [android.net.http.SslCertificate]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [android.net.http.SslCertificate$DName]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.conn.scheme.HostNameResolver]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SocketFactory]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.params.HttpParams]

Note: there were 7 duplicate class definitions.
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#duplicateclass)

Initializing...
Note: the configuration refers to the unknown class 'com.google.vending.licensing.ILicensingService'
Note: the configuration refers to the unknown class 'com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService'
Note: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatJellybean calls 'Field.getType'
Note: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference calls 'Class.getGenericSuperclass'
Note: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedField calls 'Field.getGenericType'
Note: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedField calls 'Field.getType'
Note: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedMethod calls 'Method.getGenericReturnType'
Note: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedMethod calls 'Method.getTypeParameters'
Note: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedMethod calls 'Method.getGenericParameterTypes'
Note: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter calls 'Field.getType'
Note: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter calls 'Method.getGenericReturnType'
Note: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter calls 'Field.getGenericType'
Note: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.JsonValueSerializer calls 'Method.getGenericReturnType'
Note: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeBindings calls 'Class.getTypeParameters'
Note: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeBindings calls 'Class.getGenericSuperclass'
Note: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeBindings calls 'Class.getGenericInterfaces'
Note: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory calls 'Class.getTypeParameters'
Note: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory calls 'Class.getGenericSuperclass'
Note: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory calls 'Class.getGenericInterfaces'
Note: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.ClassUtil$EnumTypeLocator calls 'Field.getType'
Note: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeBindings calls 'Class.getEnclosingClass'
Note: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeBindings calls 'Class.getDeclaringClass'
Note: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.ClassUtil calls 'Class.getEnclosingClass'
Note: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.ClassUtil calls 'Class.getEnclosingMethod'

Warning: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ext.DOMSerializer: can't find referenced class org.w3c.dom.bootstrap.DOMImplementationRegistry
Warning: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ext.DOMSerializer: can't find referenced class org.w3c.dom.bootstrap.DOMImplementationRegistry
Warning: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ext.DOMSerializer: can't find referenced class org.w3c.dom.bootstrap.DOMImplementationRegistry
Warning: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ext.DOMSerializer: can't find referenced class org.w3c.dom.bootstrap.DOMImplementationRegistry

Note: android.support.v4.media.IMediaBrowserServiceCallbacksAdapterApi21: can't find dynamically referenced class android.service.media.IMediaBrowserServiceCallbacks
Note: android.support.v4.media.IMediaBrowserServiceCallbacksAdapterApi21: can't find dynamically referenced class android.content.pm.ParceledListSlice
Note: android.support.v4.media.IMediaBrowserServiceCallbacksAdapterApi21$Stub: can't find dynamically referenced class android.service.media.IMediaBrowserServiceCallbacks$Stub
Note: android.support.v4.media.ParceledListSliceAdapterApi21: can't find dynamically referenced class android.content.pm.ParceledListSlice
Note: android.support.v4.text.ICUCompatApi23: can't find dynamically referenced class libcore.icu.ICU
Note: android.support.v4.text.ICUCompatIcs: can't find dynamically referenced class libcore.icu.ICU
Note: android.support.v7.widget.DrawableUtils: can't find dynamically referenced class android.graphics.Insets
Note: com.firebase.client.core.GaePlatform: can't find dynamically referenced class com.google.appengine.api.ThreadManager
Note: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatJellybean accesses a declared field 'icon' dynamically
      Maybe this is program field 'android.support.design.R$attr { int icon; }'
      Maybe this is program field 'android.support.design.R$id { int icon; }'
      Maybe this is program field 'android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat$Action { int icon; }'
      Maybe this is program field 'android.support.v7.appcompat.R$attr { int icon; }'
      Maybe this is program field 'android.support.v7.appcompat.R$id { int icon; }'
      Maybe this is program field 'ca.tech1st.www.redhillcarwash.R$attr { int icon; }'
      Maybe this is program field 'ca.tech1st.www.redhillcarwash.R$id { int icon; }'
      Maybe this is library field 'android.R$attr { int icon; }'
      Maybe this is library field 'android.R$id { int icon; }'
      Maybe this is library field 'android.app.LauncherActivity$ListItem { android.graphics.drawable.Drawable icon; }'
      Maybe this is library field 'android.app.Notification { int icon; }'
      Maybe this is library field 'android.app.Notification$Action { int icon; }'
      Maybe this is library field 'android.appwidget.AppWidgetProviderInfo { int icon; }'
      Maybe this is library field 'android.content.pm.PackageItemInfo { int icon; }'
      Maybe this is library field 'android.content.pm.ResolveInfo { int icon; }'
      Maybe this is library field 'android.inputmethodservice.Keyboard$Key { android.graphics.drawable.Drawable icon; }'
      Maybe this is library field 'android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech$EngineInfo { int icon; }'
Note: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatJellybean accesses a declared field 'title' dynamically
      Maybe this is program field 'android.support.design.R$attr { int title; }'
      Maybe this is program field 'android.support.design.R$id { int title; }'
      Maybe this is program field 'android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat$Action { java.lang.CharSequence title; }'
      Maybe this is program field 'android.support.v7.appcompat.R$attr { int title; }'
      Maybe this is program field 'android.support.v7.appcompat.R$id { int title; }'
      Maybe this is program field 'ca.tech1st.www.redhillcarwash.R$attr { int title; }'
      Maybe this is program field 'ca.tech1st.www.redhillcarwash.R$id { int title; }'
      Maybe this is library field 'android.R$attr { int title; }'
      Maybe this is library field 'android.R$id { int title; }'
      Maybe this is library field 'android.app.Notification$Action { java.lang.CharSequence title; }'
      Maybe this is library field 'android.preference.PreferenceActivity$Header { java.lang.CharSequence title; }'
Note: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatJellybean accesses a declared field 'actionIntent' dynamically
      Maybe this is program field 'android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat$Action { android.app.PendingIntent actionIntent; }'
      Maybe this is library field 'android.app.Notification$Action { android.app.PendingIntent actionIntent; }'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.design.widget.NavigationView { void setNavigationItemSelectedListener(android.support.design.widget.NavigationView$OnNavigationItemSelectedListener); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.design.widget.NavigationView$OnNavigationItemSelectedListener'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.design.widget.Snackbar$SnackbarLayout { void setOnLayoutChangeListener(android.support.design.widget.Snackbar$SnackbarLayout$OnLayoutChangeListener); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.design.widget.Snackbar$SnackbarLayout$OnLayoutChangeListener'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.design.widget.Snackbar$SnackbarLayout { void setOnAttachStateChangeListener(android.support.design.widget.Snackbar$SnackbarLayout$OnAttachStateChangeListener); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.design.widget.Snackbar$SnackbarLayout$OnAttachStateChangeListener'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.design.widget.TabLayout { void setOnTabSelectedListener(android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$OnTabSelectedListener); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$OnTabSelectedListener'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.design.widget.TabLayout { void setupWithViewPager(android.support.v4.view.ViewPager); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.v4.view.ViewPager'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.design.widget.TabLayout { void setTabsFromPagerAdapter(android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.v4.view.ViewPager { void setAdapter(android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.v4.view.ViewPager { void setOnAdapterChangeListener(android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$OnAdapterChangeListener); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$OnAdapterChangeListener'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.v4.view.ViewPager { void setOnPageChangeListener(android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$OnPageChangeListener); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$OnPageChangeListener'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout { void setDrawerListener(android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout$DrawerListener); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout$DrawerListener'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView { void setOnScrollChangeListener(android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView$OnScrollChangeListener); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView$OnScrollChangeListener'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout { void setPanelSlideListener(android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout$PanelSlideListener); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout$PanelSlideListener'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout { void setOnRefreshListener(android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout$OnRefreshListener); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout$OnRefreshListener'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.v7.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView { void setItemInvoker(android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder$ItemInvoker); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder$ItemInvoker'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.v7.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView { void setPopupCallback(android.support.v7.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView$PopupCallback); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.v7.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView$PopupCallback'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarContainer { void setTabContainer(android.support.v7.widget.ScrollingTabContainerView); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.v7.widget.ScrollingTabContainerView'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout { void setActionBarVisibilityCallback(android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout$ActionBarVisibilityCallback); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout$ActionBarVisibilityCallback'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView { void setPresenter(android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuPresenter); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuPresenter'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView { void setOnMenuItemClickListener(android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView$OnMenuItemClickListener); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView$OnMenuItemClickListener'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.v7.widget.ActivityChooserView { void setActivityChooserModel(android.support.v7.widget.ActivityChooserModel); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.v7.widget.ActivityChooserModel'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.v7.widget.ActivityChooserView { void setProvider(android.support.v4.view.ActionProvider); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.v4.view.ActionProvider'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout { void setAttachListener(android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout$OnAttachListener); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout$OnAttachListener'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.v7.widget.FitWindowsFrameLayout { void setOnFitSystemWindowsListener(android.support.v7.widget.FitWindowsViewGroup$OnFitSystemWindowsListener); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.v7.widget.FitWindowsViewGroup$OnFitSystemWindowsListener'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.v7.widget.FitWindowsLinearLayout { void setOnFitSystemWindowsListener(android.support.v7.widget.FitWindowsViewGroup$OnFitSystemWindowsListener); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.v7.widget.FitWindowsViewGroup$OnFitSystemWindowsListener'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView { void setAccessibilityDelegateCompat(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerViewAccessibilityDelegate); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerViewAccessibilityDelegate'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView { void setAdapter(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView { void setRecyclerListener(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$RecyclerListener); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$RecyclerListener'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView { void setLayoutManager(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView { void setRecycledViewPool(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$RecycledViewPool); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$RecycledViewPool'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView { void setViewCacheExtension(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ViewCacheExtension); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ViewCacheExtension'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView { void setChildDrawingOrderCallback(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ChildDrawingOrderCallback); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ChildDrawingOrderCallback'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView { void setOnScrollListener(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$OnScrollListener); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$OnScrollListener'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView { void setItemAnimator(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ItemAnimator); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ItemAnimator'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.v7.widget.SearchView { void setOnQueryTextListener(android.support.v7.widget.SearchView$OnQueryTextListener); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.v7.widget.SearchView$OnQueryTextListener'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.v7.widget.SearchView { void setOnCloseListener(android.support.v7.widget.SearchView$OnCloseListener); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.v7.widget.SearchView$OnCloseListener'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.v7.widget.SearchView { void setOnSuggestionListener(android.support.v7.widget.SearchView$OnSuggestionListener); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.v7.widget.SearchView$OnSuggestionListener'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.v7.widget.SearchView { void setSuggestionsAdapter(android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.v7.widget.SearchView$SearchAutoComplete { void setSearchView(android.support.v7.widget.SearchView); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.v7.widget.SearchView'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar { void setOnMenuItemClickListener(android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar$OnMenuItemClickListener); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar$OnMenuItemClickListener'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.v7.widget.ViewStubCompat { void setOnInflateListener(android.support.v7.widget.ViewStubCompat$OnInflateListener); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.v7.widget.ViewStubCompat$OnInflateListener'
Note: there were 2 references to unknown classes.
      You should check your configuration for typos.

Note: there were 18 classes trying to access generic signatures using reflection.
      You should consider keeping the signature attributes
      (using '-keepattributes Signature').

Note: there were 3 classes trying to access enclosing classes using reflection.
      You should consider keeping the inner classes attributes
      (using '-keepattributes InnerClasses').

Note: there were 1 classes trying to access enclosing methods using reflection.
      You should consider keeping the enclosing method attributes
      (using '-keepattributes InnerClasses,EnclosingMethod').

Note: there were 40 unkept descriptor classes in kept class members.
      You should consider explicitly keeping the mentioned classes
      (using '-keep').

Note: there were 8 unresolved dynamic references to classes or interfaces.
      You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.

Note: there were 3 accesses to class members by means of introspection.
      You should consider explicitly keeping the mentioned class members
      (using '-keep' or '-keepclassmembers').

Warning: there were 4 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
         You may need to add missing library jars or update their versions.
         If your code works fine without the missing classes, you can suppress
         the warnings with '-dontwarn' options.


Warning: Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
:app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.
> java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 31.045 secs
```

My build.gradle (project)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common      to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

build.gradle module

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "ca.tech1st.www.redhillcarwash"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
}
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2+'
}
```

proguard-rules.pro

> ```
> -dontwarn okio.**
> -dontwarn java.nio.file.Files
> -dontwarn java.nio.file.Path
> -dontwarn java.nio.file.OpenOption
> -dontwarn org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
> -dontwarn org.apache.http.**
> -dontwarn android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient
> -dontwarn com.android.volley.toolbox.**
> -dontwarn android.support.**
> -dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
> ```

I am really stuck and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `Please correct the above warnings first.`, where are the above warnings? There has got to be more then just that.

Comment: I edited my post and provided all the information I could

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at this message

> Please correct the above warnings first.

I see that there were 4 messages posted with a WARNING level,

```
Warning: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ext.DOMSerializer: can't find referenced class org.w3c.dom.bootstrap.DOMImplementationRegistry
Warning: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ext.DOMSerializer: can't find referenced class org.w3c.dom.bootstrap.DOMImplementationRegistry
Warning: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ext.DOMSerializer: can't find referenced class org.w3c.dom.bootstrap.DOMImplementationRegistry
Warning: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ext.DOMSerializer: can't find referenced class org.w3c.dom.bootstrap.DOMImplementationRegistry
```

It appears as if the compilation process does not have the `jackson-databind` dependancy declared.

Try adding this to the *dependancies* section of your build.gradle file

```
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.7.3'
```

Comment: I did as suggested and I get the following errors  Warning:com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ext.PathDeserializer: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Paths
Warning:com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.JacksonAnnotationIntrospector$Java7Support: can't find referenced class java.beans.Transient
Warning:com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.JacksonAnnotationIntrospector$Java7Support: can't find referenced class java.beans.ConstructorProperties
Warning:com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.JacksonAnnotationIntrospector$Java7Support: can't find referenced class java.beans.Transient

Comment: I do appreciate the suggestions.  Thanks

Comment: @Paul_D
I am getting the same warning as you've mentioned in your comment. Did you. Did u find a solution for this

Answer (score 4):

Add the following to your `proguard` file

```
-dontwarn com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.**
```

Answer (score 0):

With the help above from Matt and this post 
[What ProGuard configuration do I need for Firebase on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26273929/what-proguard-configuration-do-i-need-for-firebase-on-android)

I was able to use proguard and my app with obfuscated code runs.