# Android minifyEnabled true for firebase

Tags: android, firebase

I am beginner in android and I have written code like this. If I enable minifyEnabled = true, that particular code is not triggering and I also don't know how to debug properly (I can only log) . How shall I do?

```
    DatabaseReference database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("ConversationUser").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid());
    database.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            ConversationUser conversationUser = dataSnapshot.getValue(ConversationUser.class);


            Log.e("Chat", conversationUser.toString());
            Log.e("Chat Status", conversationUser.getStatus());
            String status = conversationUser.getStatus();

            if (status != null && status.toLowerCase().equals("active")) {
                //TODO: this never trigger if minifyEnabled = true
                retrieveConversation(conversationUser.getId());
                EventBus.getDefault().post(new ChatDetailAdapter.ReceiveMessage());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            Log.e("ChatHelper", "onChildChanged");

            ConversationUser conversationUser = dataSnapshot.getValue(ConversationUser.class);
            if (conversationUser.getStatus().toLowerCase().equals("delete")) {

                for(Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Conversation>> it = mainMessage.getConversations().entrySet().iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
                    Map.Entry<String, Conversation> entry = it.next();
                    if(entry.getKey().equals(conversationUser.getId())) {
                        it.remove();
                    }
                }

                sortConversation();
                EventBus.getDefault().post(new ChatDetailAdapter.ReceiveMessage());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            EventBus.getDefault().post(new ChatDetailAdapter.RemoveMessage());
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            EventBus.getDefault().post(new ChatDetailAdapter.ReceiveMessage());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: may be you have to "keep" that class file or library using proguard-rule.pro   did you refer the docs about Proguard

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on that? @JayThummar. I have written that in class "ChatHelper"

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start/

Comment: minifyEnabled = true   is used for to enable proguard rule that is basically used to provide security to code and shrink the resources if you enable it .  If you search for the file named as proguard-rules.pro this  file is used for proguard-rule  so when some library of class file not able to run properly because of this we have to keep that library from proguard .  There are many answer of  your question is given to keep firebase library check it and try again

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Possibly your models are obfuscate and that's why your code is not working properly. To fix it, you will need to keep the folder where you store all your `FirebaseModels` in your proguard files.

```
# Firebase
-keep class com.myAppPackage.folderWhereYouSaveYourModels.** { *; }
```

Also you will need to add a few lines more, you can check the documentation:

> When using Firebase Realtime Database in your app along with ProGuard
>   you need to consider how your model objects will be serialized and
>   deserialized after obfuscation. If you use
>   DataSnapshot.getValue(Class) or DatabaseReference.setValue(Object) to
>   read and write data you will need to add rules to the
>   proguard-rules.pro file:

```
# Add this global rule
-keepattributes Signature

# This rule will properly ProGuard all the model classes in
# the package com.yourcompany.models. Modify to fit the structure
# of your app.
-keepclassmembers class com.yourcompany.models.** {
  *;
}
```

Hope that it will help you!

Comment: Ok, I updated it adding an extra `keep` for the specific folder where you store your FirebaseModels

Comment: That looks like the most accurate answer!

Answer (score 4):

Open your **`proguard-rules.pro`** and Add

```
-keep class com.firebase.** { *; }
```

> When using Firebase Realtime Database in your app along with ProGuard
>   you need to consider how your model objects will be serialized and
>   deserialized after obfuscation.

```
# Add this global rule
-keepattributes Signature

# This rule will properly ProGuard all the model classes in
# the package com.yourcompany.models. Modify to fit the structure
# of your app.
-keepclassmembers class com.yourcompany.models.** {
  *;
}
```

For more details, see [**`Proguard Rule`**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start/).

Comment: @KhantThuLinn okay.

Comment: Thanks. It is okay now.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation is not great in this regard. The only solution that worked for me was found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63824111/4157431)

You can "individually" exclude your `models` that firebase uses by adding the `@keep` annotation to those classes.

```
import androidx.annotation.Keep;

@Keep
public class User {
    public static String userId;
    ....
}
```

As an additional measure, I do the same for my Database calls as well. Not sure if that's necessary though.