# Proguard issue when trying to login with Firebase UI Auth

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, proguard

I am using Firebase UI Auth to login into the application. The debug build is working fine but when I try to login with the release build the application crashes with an error.

```
2018-10-02 14:05:23.072 4827-4866/io.palette E/c.b.a.J: Creating atomic field updaters failed
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: No field streamClosed in class Lc/b/a/J$c; (declaration of 'c.b.a.J$c' appears in /data/app/io.palette-1/base.apk)
    at java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicIntegerFieldUpdater$AtomicIntegerFieldUpdaterImpl.<init>(AtomicIntegerFieldUpdater.java:380)
    at java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicIntegerFieldUpdater.newUpdater(AtomicIntegerFieldUpdater.java:58)
    at c.b.a.J.<clinit>(:77)
    at c.b.a.c.c(:420)
    at c.b.a.c.a(:395)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.f.zzd.<init>(:102)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.b.zzg.zza(:1217)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.b.zzi.run()
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:272)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.g.zza$zza.run(:190)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

What could be the possible reason for this?

Comment: check this post
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26273929/what-proguard-configuration-do-i-need-for-firebase-on-android

Comment: @KonstantinVolkov I have already include this 

`-keep class com.firebase.** { *; }
-keep class org.shaded.apache.** { *; }
-keepnames class com.shaded.fasterxml.jackson.** { *; }
-keepnames class javax.servlet.** { *; }
-keepnames class org.ietf.jgss.** { *; }
-dontwarn org.w3c.dom.**
-dontwarn org.joda.time.**
-dontwarn org.shaded.apache.**
-dontwarn org.ietf.jgss.**
-dontwarn com.firebase.ui.auth.**`

But still not working

Comment: So as i see you have a problem with 
" at com.google.firebase.firestore.g.zza$zza.run(:190)"
While in your proguard cfg it is -keep class com.firebase.** { *; }