# Firebase InApp Messaging not working after sign apk

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-in-app-messaging

We are using Firebase InApp Messaging service in our android app. But when test with debug mode its working fine and getting proper message. But while signing apk and check with instance id not getting dialog or proper message.

Any one have idea about it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51360250/firebase-ui-authentication-with-google-fails-with-message-code10-message10/51360406)** out.

Answer (score 1):

You may have configured your Google Play Console for app signing.
In that case google has generated a new SHA1 key for your application. You now need to 
replace your original keys with those provided by google play console.
You can find generated keys by going to **Release management > App signing**.

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

There might be some obfuscation related issue as in general the signed apks for release are obfuscated using proguard rules in android.
Please check if in your proguard rules you have made required changes related to firebase.
For refference you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26273929/what-proguard-configuration-do-i-need-for-firebase-on-android) and [this](https://github.com/googlearchive/AndroidChat/blob/master/app/proguard-rules.pro).

Comment: Adding proguard rules for Firebase in second link solved my issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1.You have to add the release SHA1 certificate fingerprints in firebase console to work when you signed the apk.
2.If you want inApp messaging should work in both debug and release mode. Then keep both SHA1 certificate fingerprint in Firebase console and download the google_services.json file and add in the project. Then it should work in both release and debug mode.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Already uploaded SHA1 certification and also having google_services.json file in project still the same issue.