# Firebase google Sign in won't work after applying Proguard

Tags: java, android, firebase, proguard

When I disable the proguard in Android, Firebase Google Sign in works properly, but when I enable it, it won't works only when I signed bundle apk.
In normal debug, it works. My Google Sign in code is here

`package com.example.dhop.Activity;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;`

`import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;`

`import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;`

`import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;`

`import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.example.dhop.ModelClass.UpdateHelper;`

`import com.example.dhop.R;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount;`

`import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInClient;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException;`

`import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthCredential;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;`

`import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;`

`public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    static final int GOOGLE_SIGN_IN = 123;
    FirebaseAuth mAuth;`

`Button btn_login, btn_logout;
    TextView text;
    ImageView image;`

`ProgressBar progressBar;
    GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient;
    @Override`

`protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

`btn_login = findViewById(R.id.login);
        btn_logout = findViewById(R.id.logout);
        text = findViewById(R.id.text);`

   `image = findViewById(R.id.image);
        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progress_circular);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();`

`GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))`

`.requestEmail()
                .build();
        mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);`

`btn_login.setOnClickListener(v -> SignInGoogle());
        btn_logout.setOnClickListener(v -> Logout());
        if (mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {`

`FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
            updateUI(user); } }`

`public void SignInGoogle() {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();`

`startActivityForResult(signInIntent, GOOGLE_SIGN_IN); }
    private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
        Log.d("TAG", "firebaseAuthWithGoogle:" + acct.getId());`

`AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)`

`.addOnCompleteListener(this, task -> {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);`

`Log.d("TAG", "signInWithCredential:success");
                        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                        updateUI(user);`

`} else {
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        Log.w("TAG", "signInWithCredential:failure",`

`task.getException());
                       Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",`

`Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        updateUI(null); } });  }`

`@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);`

`if (requestCode == GOOGLE_SIGN_IN) {
            Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);`

`try {
                GoogleSignInAccount account = task.getResult(ApiException.class);`

`             if (account != null) firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
            } catch (ApiException e) {
                Log.w("TAG", "Google sign in failed", e); } } }

`

`private void updateUI(FirebaseUser user) {
        if (mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,`

` MainNavActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish(); } else {

`

`text.setText("Firebase Login \n");
            Picasso.get().load(R.drawable.ic_firebase_logo).into(image);
            image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`

`btn_logout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            btn_login.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); } }`

`private void Logout() {
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
        mGoogleSignInClient.signOut().addOnCompleteListener(this,`

`task -> updateUI(null));  }`

Comment: post your proguard file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What ProGuard configuration do I need for Firebase on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26273929/what-proguard-configuration-do-i-need-for-firebase-on-android)

Comment: # Add project specific ProGuard rules here.
# You can control the set of applied configuration files using the
# proguardFiles setting in build.gradle.
# For more details, see
#   http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html
# If your project uses WebView with JS, uncomment the following
# and specify the fully qualified class name to the JavaScript interface
# class:
#-keepclassmembers class fqcn.of.javascript.interface.for.webview {
#   public *;
#}
# Uncomment this to preserve the line number information for
# debugging stack traces.
All default thigs

Comment: Can I encript only which file I want. In default all files are encrypted or locked. Can I write any code that only lock that particular class. This will be helpful. Cause I'm unable to find out for which class google sigin in method stops working !

Comment: see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26273929/what-proguard-configuration-do-i-need-for-firebase-on-android#answer-26274623

Comment: @Lingeshwaran -keep class com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInClient.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApi.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.firebase.auth.GoogleSignInClient.** { *; }
-keep class * extends com.example.dhop.Activity.MainActivity.** { *; }
-keep class com.firebase.** { *; }
-keep class org.apache.** { *; }
-keepnames class com.fasterxml.jackson.** { *; }
-keepnames class javax.servlet.** { *; }
-keepnames class org.ietf.jgss.** { *; }
-dontwarn org.apache.**
-dontwarn org.w3c.dom.**
Add this. Won't work

Comment: I think my updateUI sytem won't work. How can I keep it from proguard ?

Comment: -keep com.example.dhop.Activity.MainActivity { updateUI; }
I'm getting error of this line. This orientation is wrong ?

Comment: How to keep a method in a class in proguard ?

Comment: My problem not solved yet !